# database.update not working sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Okey , now this was the query I used to update a single cell into my table.

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TodoDBHelper.TODO_DONE, 1);

    database.update(TodoDBHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, TodoDBHelper.TODO_ID + " = ? " + id, null);
```

TodoDBHelper.TODO_ID was my constant for indicating column id is the value which passed into this method.

is throwing nullpoinerException (I've tried it in try catch)

I 've checked a lot of links ,not quite understanding what to do 
adises needed!

here's the log (without using try catch (app crashes also))

```
    06-18 08:08:15.256: E/InputEventReceiver(22994): Exception dispatching input event.
    06-18 08:08:15.256: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22994): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
    06-18 08:08:15.356: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22994): java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-18 08:08:15.356: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22994):  at com.compony.todolist.data.TodoDataSource.updateById(TodoDataSource.java:115)
    06-18 08:08:15.356: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22994):  at com.compony.todolist.adapt.RowAdapter$1.handleSwipeRight(RowAdapter.java:158)
    06-18 08:08:15.356: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22994):  at com.compony.todolist.adapt.RowAdapter$1.onTouch(RowAdapter.java:124)
    06-18 08:08:15.356: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22994):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7379)
     06-18 08:08:15.356: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22994):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2203)
     06-18 08:08:15.356: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22994):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1938)
     06-18 08:08:15.356: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22994):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
     06-18 08:08:15.356: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22994):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1952)
     06-18 08:08:15.356: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22994):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
     06-18 08:08:15.356: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22994):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1952)
      06-18 08:08:15.356: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22994):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2209)
      06-18 08:08:15.356: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22994):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1952)
      06-18 08:08:15.356: E/MessageQueue-JNI(22994):    at
```

Comment: Please post logcat exception.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in `id` in the `whereArgs` parameter, you are appending it to the `where` parameter. 
The call to update expects an argument in `whereArgs` since you have put a ? placeholder in the `where` parameter.

Instead, do this:

```
database.update(TodoDBHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, 
     TodoDBHelper.TODO_ID + " = ? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
```

Comment: its not working .... do you think its something else , because I got the same logcat error again...!!

Comment: what is the exact code at the line where the NullPointerException occurs?

Comment: @ Thorstenvv line no 115 which is the database.update code I just posted ? ..dou you have any idea how would a null pointer exception would be thrown when we tries to update ?? if I commented out that line then it not showing no errors...!!!

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and inspect if database is not null?

Comment: @ Thorstenvv I tried setting a breakpoint but eclipse is showing No source found on debug.